# PHP not outputting files on a cron job on a Linux server

Tags: php, linux, cron

I am trying to configure a cron job on a Linux server to run a PHP script every hour. The job is supposed to update (i.e. write over) a number of .ics files every hour in another directory. When I run

```
crontab -l
```

The output is

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/.../index.php > /var/.../log.txt
```

Now, running this line of code works like a charm and replaces the .ics files when done manually in the terminal, but every time the cron job runs, it fails to overwrite the .ics files. Furthermore, log.txt is empty when I check it. I also set the permissions for index.php to 755, but it still doesn't work. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: What happens if you run `env -i /usr/bin/php -f /var/.../index.php`? Also, you might want to add `STDERR` in your log too: `2>&1 > /var/.../log.txt`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. When I ran it with env -i, it turned out that getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") wasn't outputting anything. I'll see what happens on the next cron job.